# C# ASP.NET Account Lockout, Disabled, Expired and Password Expired

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this has been asked a couple of times already but I am still new to C# and don't quite know how to use the answers provided to other questions.

I am using .Net 4.5.1.

I have a site where you enter a domain user ID and the domain.  I have written the site in Classic ASP and VBScript.  It then displays the account status, IE. display name, UPN, email address, is the password expired (and when it will expire), password locked status, account expired (never or date or expired with date) and whether the account is disabledd.  I am trying to convert to ASP.NET and C#.

I have the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strUserToSearchFor = (string)(Session["txbUserID"]);
    string strUserDomain = (string)(Session["drpDomain"]);
    string strDomainFQDN = "";
    Dictionary<string, string> dicDomainFQDN = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN1", "DC=1,DC=domain,DC=com");
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN2", "DC=2,DC=domain,DC=com");
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN3", "DC=3,DC=domain,DC=com");

    if (dicDomainFQDN.ContainsKey(strUserDomain.ToUpper()))
    {
        strDomainFQDN = dicDomainFQDN[strUserDomain.ToUpper()];
    }

    dicDomainFQDN.Clear();

    AuthenticationTypes ADAT = AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous;
    ADAT = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    string strADSearchUsername = "username";
    string strADSearchPassword = "password";

    DirectoryEntry ADConn = ADConn = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + strDomainFQDN, strADSearchUsername, strADSearchPassword, ADAT);

    strADSearchUsername = string.Empty;
    strADSearchPassword = string.Empty;

    DirectorySearcher ADSearch = new DirectorySearcher(ADConn);

    ADSearch.Filter = "maxPwdAge=*";

    SearchResultCollection ADMaxPwdAgeResult = ADSearch.FindAll();

    long intMaxPwdDays = 0;

    if (ADMaxPwdAgeResult.Count >= 1)
    {
        Int64 intMaxPwdAge = (Int64)ADMaxPwdAgeResult[0].Properties["maxPwdAge"][0];
        intMaxPwdDays = intMaxPwdAge / -864000000000;
    }

    ADMaxPwdAgeResult.Dispose();

    ADSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ADSearch.PageSize = 1001;

    ADSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + strUserToSearchFor + "))";

    strUserToSearchFor = string.Empty;

    SearchResult ADResult = ADSearch.FindOne();

    if (ADResult != null)
    {
        string strName = "";
        string strMail = "";
        string strMobile = "";
        string strUPN = "";
        string strPwdLastSet = "";
        string strPwdLocked = "";
        string strAccountEpiryDate = "";
        string strAccountDisabled = "";

        strName = ADResult.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
        strMail = ADResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        strMobile = ADResult.Properties["mobile"][0].ToString();
        strUPN = ADResult.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString();

        if (ADResult.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Count > 0)
        {
            DateTime dtmPwdLastSet = new DateTime();
            dtmPwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(ADResult.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0]));
            dtmPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.AddDays(intMaxPwdDays);
            if (dtmPwdLastSet <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                strPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.ToString() + " (Expired)";
            }
            else
            {
                strPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strPwdLastSet = "Change at next logon";
        }
        ...
```

After that though, I am not sure on how to get the password locked, the account disabled and account expiry date if there is one.

For password locked I tried:

```
        if (ADResult.Properties["IsAccountLocked"].Count > 0)
        {
            strPwdLocked = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            strPwdLocked = "No";
        }
```

For account expiry I tried the same approach as the password expiry but it doesn't pick up that there is an expiry date.  With the account disabled I found a function that will do the trick (I suspect) but I have no idea how to call the function from within the my script.

```
private bool IsActive(DirectoryEntry de)
{
    if (de.NativeGuid == null) return false;
    int flags = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
    return !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
}
```

Any help with be really appreciated.

Also, since I added the max password age code the page takes 3 times as long.  Is there a way to get the max password age for a domain a lot faster?

---

Ok, I figured out the disabled part:

```
DirectoryEntry ADEntry = ADResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
int intUserDisabled = (int)ADEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
bool bolAccountDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(intUserDisabled & 2);
if (bolAccountDisabled == true)
{
    strAccountDisabled = "Yes";
}
```

This also helps to check if the password is locked.

```
bool bolPasswordLocked = Convert.ToBoolean(intUserDisabled & 16);
```

Still need help with the account expiry date please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got the solution.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strUserToSearchFor = (string)(Session["txbUserID"]);
    string strUserDomain = (string)(Session["drpDomain"]);
    string strDomainFQDN = "";

    Dictionary<string, string> dicDomainFQDN = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN1", "DC=1,DC=domain,DC=com");
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN2", "DC=2,DC=domain,DC=com");
    dicDomainFQDN.Add("DOMAIN3", "DC=3,DC=domain,DC=com");

    if (dicDomainFQDN.ContainsKey(strUserDomain.ToUpper()))
    {
        strDomainFQDN = dicDomainFQDN[strUserDomain.ToUpper()];
    }

    AuthenticationTypes ADAT = AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous;
    ADAT = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    DirectoryEntry ADConn = ADConn = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + strDomainFQDN, strADSearchUsername, strADSearchPassword, ADAT);

    DirectorySearcher ADSearch = new DirectorySearcher(ADConn);

    ADSearch.Filter = "maxPwdAge=*";

    SearchResultCollection ADMaxPwdAgeResult = ADSearch.FindAll();

    long intMaxPwdDays = 0;

    if (ADMaxPwdAgeResult.Count >= 1)
    {
        Int64 intMaxPwdAge = (Int64)ADMaxPwdAgeResult[0].Properties["maxPwdAge"][0];
        intMaxPwdDays = intMaxPwdAge / -864000000000;
    }

    ADSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ADSearch.PageSize = 1001;

    ADSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + strUserToSearchFor + "))";

    strUserToSearchFor = string.Empty;

    SearchResult ADResult = ADSearch.FindOne();

    if (ADResult != null)
    {
        DirectoryEntry ADEntry = ADResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

        string strName = "";
        string strMail = "";
        string strMobile = "";
        string strUPN = "";
        string strPwdLastSet = "";
        string strPwdLocked = "No";
        string strAccountEpiryDate = "";
        string strAccountDisabled = "No";

        int intFlags = (int)ADEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

        strName = ADEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
        strMail = ADEntry.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        strMobile = ADResult.Properties["mobile"][0].ToString();
        strUPN = ADEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString();

        // Get the date the password was last set and check if it has expired
        if (ADEntry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Count > 0)
        {
            DateTime dtmPwdLastSet = new DateTime();
            dtmPwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(ADEntry.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0]));
            dtmPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.AddDays(intMaxPwdDays);
            if (dtmPwdLastSet <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                strPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.ToString() + " (Expired)";
            }
            else
            {
                strPwdLastSet = dtmPwdLastSet.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strPwdLastSet = "Change at next logon";
        }

        // Check if the password is locked
        bool bolPwdLocked = Convert.ToBoolean(intFlags & 0x00000010);
        if (bolPwdLocked == true)
            strPwdLocked = "Yes";

        // Check if the account has expired
        if (ADResult.Properties["accountExpires"].Count > 0)
        {
            DateTime dtmAccountExpires = new DateTime();
            dtmAccountExpires = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(ADResult.Properties["accountExpires"][0]));
            if (dtmAccountExpires <= DateTime.Today)
            {
                strAccountEpiryDate = dtmAccountExpires.ToString() + " (Expired)";
            }
            else
            {
                strAccountEpiryDate = dtmAccountExpires.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strAccountEpiryDate = "Never";
        }

        // Check if the account is disabled
        bool bolAccountDisabled = Convert.ToBoolean(intFlags & 0x00000002);
        if (bolAccountDisabled == true)
            strAccountDisabled = "Yes";
    }
}
```